# GestureOverlayView

Tags: android, gestureoverlayview

How to work with the `GestureOverlayView` control, Please explain with some example.

Comment: [this is how you ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725005/getting-a-gestureoverlayview)

Comment: Try this link that defenalety useful to u http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very good tutorial.
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html